Retrofit logs are not showing, Android Studio
I'm starting to learn Android(kotlin, mvvm, coroutine). I'm trying to call(GET) this api which is provided from The Movie DB.
http:// api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=#################

I am only getting response error and no idea what's happening since I don't see the request and response in log. So, put a logging to retrofit client.
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory


class MovieListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MovieListViewModel by viewModels {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build()
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val movieService = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.themoviedb.org/3")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()
            .create(MovieService::class.java)
        val repository = MovieRepository(movieService)
        MovieListViewModelFactory(repository)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        val adapter = MovieListAdapter(requireContext())
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        Log.d("MovieListFragment", "Test log to check if logging works")

        viewModel.movies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { movies ->
            adapter.submitList(movies)
        })

        viewModel.error.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { error ->
            print(error)
        })

        if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(requireContext())) {
            viewModel.fetchPopularMovies()
        } else {
            print("No internet..")
        }
    }
}

interface MovieService {
    @GET("/discover/movie")
    suspend fun getPopularMovies(
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
        @Query("sort_by") sortBy: String
    ): MovieResponse
}

class MovieRepository(private val movieService: MovieService) {
    suspend fun getPopularMovies(): MovieResponse {
        return movieService.getPopularMovies("##################", "popularity.desc")
    }
}

class MovieListViewModel(private val repository: MovieRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _movies = MutableLiveData<List<Movie>>()
    val movies: LiveData<List<Movie>> get() = _movies

    private val _error = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val error: LiveData<String> get() = _error

    fun fetchPopularMovies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = repository.getPopularMovies()
                _movies.postValue(response.results)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _error.postValue(e.message)
            }
        }
    }
}

Also put some network security setting since the endpoint is not https.
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.themoviedb.org</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MvvMTest"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>

Logcat is working fine in Android Studio. The problem must be in my code. Any Idea?


hoi, can u share your viewmodel code?

I replaced Moshi for Gson. The issue is gone. Now I see the log. I don't want to answer my own question tho.

okay nice that you solved the problem on your own.

Add internet permission to the manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


I put it now and tried again. Still no network logging is showing.
